# Running Excel.run() from inside a web worker

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I've seen that is possible to use a web worker for doing heavy stuff and not blocking the UI thread. But from what I've tested there is no possiblity to call `Excel.run()` from within the worker.

The thing is:
How can I run thousands of `Excel.run()` without getting `Wait for previous operation to complete exception` ?

I've tried many things, like doing in batches of 10 and waiting for every batch to finish, but still get `Wait for previous operation to complete exception` error sometimes.

There is also a need that inside each `Excel.run()` to call context.sync().

Comment: Excel.run can only run in a JavaScript engine embedded in Office, so it can't run in a web worker. Could you provide more info about your scenario? I suspect that you could do what you want in a single Excel.run.

Comment: I've wrapped everything in an `Excel.run`, but still get wait for previous operation to complete if for exemple there will be 500-1000 parallel `context.sync()` calls

Comment: What do you think I should further try?

Comment: Do you have a sample which has a huge amount of formulas like 200.000 formulas?

Comment: Btw, I had for ex: 1500 formulas with `range.load()` and only one `context.sync()` call, but it failed with wait for previous operation to complete

Comment: Most important is if you can somehow add a functionality to update excel from a webworker because having to much stuff doing on the UI thread will block scrolling and overall functionality of excel.

Comment: Our usecase is: 
0. return 1000 promises from a custom function
1. Have 1000 requests.
2. add/remove bingings
3. update promises values

This operations kind of terminate excel and freezes everything

Comment: You should not be calling context.sync that often. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern